# Can we access Mysql database using apache cordova without using php

Tags: mysql, cordova, phonegap-cli

I am a student and I am creating android app using apache cordova.
I want to access MySql Database of hosted website using apache cordova.
Please suggest me how can I do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want the data or really need to connect to the 3306 port of MySQL using MySQL's own protocol? Sure the former and you are suggested to have a server which talks with your App using HTTP and query your MySQL server.

Comment: I want to retrieve data from MySql

Comment: Don't do that. MySQL is not a very secure protocol, plus you would have to hard-code mySQL user data in your app that anyone could get from there. You need to have something in between. I've heard there's pre-made scripts for these kinds of scenarios, though.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing that DB, you need to make a server API, you dont have to make it in PHP, there are a lot of technologies, but you can't do it directly from the client side (cordova).

Google for API REST or web service and choose your technology.